# Did the bounty to win +1 shed level work from 3 to 4 or only 2 to 3?

Tags: ogame

Self answering question as I always have a doubt :

Did the +1 shed level work from 3 to 4 or only 2 to 3 ?

(in French :)

`Récompense : +1 niveau à un hangar (jusqu'au niveau 3 maximum)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :
only from 2 to 3 (3 is max the game can give you).

By the way : it's the lower shed level that get the +1, so you should probably go for 3/3/2 before calling a merchant.